# My C++ program terminates

Tags: c++

Hi everyone below is my code. After I click run button it terminates automatically before showing any output. Can anyone help me ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "StudentReviewSystem.h"
#include <string>
#include "Course.h"

StudentReviewSystem ::StudentReviewSystem()
 {
 }
 StudentReviewSystem :: ~StudentReviewSystem()
 {
 }


 void StudentReviewSystem :: addCourse( const int courseId, const string courseName )
{   
int numOfCourse = 0;
Course* C ;

    if(numOfCourse==0)
    {
        C = new Course[numOfCourse+1];
        C[0].courseId= courseId ;
        C[0].courseName = courseName ;
        cout<< " Course " <<courseId<< "  has been added"<<endl;
        numOfCourse++;

    }

 else
 {
     int x = 0 ;
     for(int i = 0; i< numOfCourse; i++)
     {
         if(C[i].courseId == courseId)
         {
             cout<< " Course " <<courseId<< "  already exists"<<endl;
             x++;
         }

         if(x == 0) 
     {
         Course* tmp = C ;
         C = new Course[numOfCourse+1];
        for(int i = 0; i< numOfCourse ; i++)
        {
            C[i] = tmp[i];
        }
        C[numOfCourse].courseId = courseId;
        C[numOfCourse].courseName = courseName;
        delete[] tmp ;
        numOfCourse++;

     }

     }

 }

}
int main()
{
    StudentReviewSystem S;
    S.addCourse( 101, "Algorithms and Programming" );
    S.addCourse( 201, "Fundamental Structures of Computer Science I" );
    S.addCourse( 101, "Algorithms and Programming" );
}
```

Comment: Time to compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and to learn how to **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`, at least on Linux).

Comment: a side note: numOfCourse is being set to `0` each time you call your function. you probably want that to be a member variable, not a local variable.

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Comment: If I make it static it doesnt set to 0 but again my program terminates.

Comment: Ok, but what output do you expect?

Comment: Course 101 has been added
Course 201 has been added

Comment: Course 101 already exists

Comment: Why are you making your own linked list? It looks like you need to read up on the [Standard Library](http://cppreference.com/). If tje exercise is to roll your own, `StudentReviewSystem` should have no knowledge of how `Course` implements that.

Comment: This is because it is said that you should use dynamic array in your homework.

Comment: Yes that is true. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Address (@name) your comments, edit your question!

Answer (score 1):

If by terminating you mean closing the terminal window, then try running `system("pause");` at the end of main.

Comment: I tried but is does not work. My program gives bad alloc error

Comment: Check correctness of, or share with us, the constructor of Course class.

Comment: using namespace std;
class Course
{
public:
    int courseId;
    string courseName;
    Course();
};

Comment: That is my Course.h class

Comment: But probably this bad allocation is in the implementation of Course class constructor. You supplied only the definition of the class.

Comment: Actually there is only constructor definition in course class

Comment: I think something is wrong about numOfCourse variable. But I could not solve it

Comment: If the constructor of `Course` was empty, you would get messages you put onto cout. It **has** to be a bug in `Course::Course()`.

Comment: I did it in that way too

Comment: After making constructor of `Course` empty messages get printed. The logic error is still there (101 is added to times) because the local, automatic variable numOfCourses is being always initialised with 0.

Comment: Also how can I access the Course's class methods in StudentReviewSystem class

Comment: Then how can I fix numOfCourses ??

Comment: How to call method of an object is very basic question, that is answered in **every** C++ book. I recommend reading one of them.

Comment: `pObj->method()` or `(*pObj).method()`

Comment: error: request for member 'makeAlloc' in 'C', which is of pointer type 'Course*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|